# Add array to two-dimensional array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to restructure output which gives me an array such as

```
   (2) [12.8494951, 77.6587404]
   (2) [12.8499, 77.6536]
```

and I want to turn it into a multidimensional array that looks like this

```
   [[12.8494951,77.6587404],[12.8499, 77.6536]]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the input of the function? I see two arrays, not one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: This is not a two dimensional array. This is an array that contains arrays

Comment: JS doesn't has md arrays only jugged

Comment: Please share the code that creates such output.

Answer (score 2):

Just push incoming arrays into one array, like this.

```
const groupIntoTwoDem = (arr1, arr2) => [arr1, arr2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could catch all parameters for a new array with [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
const getArray = (...array) => array;

console.log(getArray([12.8494951, 77.6587404], [12.8499, 77.6536]));
```